# The area of all regions where all |x_i|> r for n-dimensional hypersphere (radius r) inside the unit hypersphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I am looking to find the ratio of all the areas of A1 (the region where $|x_i|> r$ $\forall x_i$ i={1...n}) with respect to the area/volume for the hypersphere with radius 1 in n-dimensions, $S_1$. 
Even if a simple solution isn't possible a relatively decent upper bound would be worthwhile.

In the 2D case depicted an upper bound is relatively simple by assuming A1 is part of the square with length $a = (1-r^2)^{0.5}$. Thus $A1 = \frac{a^2}{2}+V(\text{segment})<\frac{a^2}{2}$ and then the ratio of the area occupied by all A1s is $\frac{\sum A1}{V_2(S_1)} < \frac{4\frac{a^2}{2}}{\pi}$, where $V_n(S_1)$ is the volume of the n-dimensional unit sphere

I tried generalising this for n-dimensional spheres as

$a = (1- (n-1)r^2)^{0.5}$

$\frac{\sum A1}{V_n(S_1)} < \frac{2^n\frac{a^n}{n}}{V_n(S_1)}$

I am not sure this generalisation is correct/valid due the weird way high dimensional shapes begin to behave?

Also it breaks down for very small $r$ such that $1 <\frac{2^n\frac{a^n}{n}}{V_n(S_1)} $ which is logical given that my estimation of the A1 area is an overestimate, as such I was wondering if there is a more accurate way to estimate A1? I'm not sure if I need to find the area of conic segments (I am aware of the paper by Li regarding this volume).

I am also aware that this is only valid for $r<\sqrt{\frac{1}{d}}$

[image]

Comment: The hard part is obviously calculating the volume of $a_n(r)$ (the volume of points $x$ that fulfill both $x_i \ge r \forall i=1..n$ and $\sum_{x=1}^{n} x_i^2 \le 1$) in $n$ dimensions, i.e. the intersection between the unit hypersphere and an axis-aligned hypercube $(r,...,r)-(1,...,1)$. The total volume is $A_n(r) = 2^n a_n(r)$. The desired ratio is then $A_n(r) / V_n = 2^n a_n(r) / V_n$, where $V_n$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional hypersphere ($n$-ball), $V_n = \pi^{n/2} / \Gamma(n/2 + 1)$. The $a_n(r)$ are not cones in $n \ge 3$.

Comment: I agree, this why I'm just interested in perhaps finding a simple upper bound for $a_n(r)$ and I can then test this using Monte Carlo integration

Comment: I'd be tempted to *start* with Monte Carlo integration. For 32 $n$ and say 32 $r$ you'd do one thousand cases. Say integration per case taking 30 seconds (millions to a billion points per case, depending on what kind of calculation power you have), that'd be an overnight job. The resulting $f(n, r)$ might/should have features that help looking at the algebraic solutions.

Comment: I did, some MC runs and when $r=0$ as this will result in the largest area of $a_n(r)$, and based on my results the upper bound is $a_n(r)<0.5^n$, this again logically makes sense as when $r=0$ then hypersphere is divided into equally space segments.

Comment: That makes sense, but isn't terribly useful, in my humble opinion, as $r=0$ is obviously the maximum. Also, because the corner of $a_n(r)$ is at $(r, ..., r)$, i.e. at distance $\sqrt{n r^2} = r \sqrt{n}$, when $r \sqrt{n} \ge 1$ the volume is zero; i.e. $a_n(r) = 0$ if $r \ge 1/\sqrt{n}$.  However, many samples at different $r$ and $n$ would allow for experimental fitting. Simply printing the $f(n, r)$ surface in 3D might bring additional insight. Although the $a(n, r)$ itself would be interesting by itself, too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm setting up the runs now and will post the surface I plot. Tbh for my application the crude upper bound of the maximum works because I have an event which occurs in this region with a probability of $0.5^n$ and just need to show that as n increases this probability of the whole event occuring so $a_n(r)0.5^n$ tends towards 0 as n increases. But of course finding a more accurate solution would be interesting and more useful for lower dimensional settings of my application.