# Ratio of the volume of a bounded region in the unit hypersphere

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

How can I find the ratio of the volume of a region in the unit n-dimensional hypersphere where for a radius $0<r<1$, the region is bounded such that

$r^2<\sum_{i=\{1...n\}}x_i^2<1$ ; $\sum_{j=\{1...m\}}x_j^2<r^2$ for a given $m\in\{1...n-1\}$.

I've been trying to think about this problem but I am finding it hard relating the volume of the condition $\sum_{j=\{1...m\}}x_j^2<r^2$ to the volume of the area $r^2<\sum_{i=\{1...n\}}x_i^2<1$.

Comment: I would start with $n=3$. Also, do you mean $r^2$ when describing the bounds?

Comment: Ah yes, my typo

Comment: @Nick the issue is that when $n>3$ any reasoning used for $n=3$ will breakdown for higher dimensions.

Comment: But at least, you will be able to check the general solution by plugging n=3 into it... And I still think you might get some intuition about what the region looks like (but you may have done that already).

Comment: yes, this is a generalisation and extension of a question i previously asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2819657/the-area-of-all-regions-where-all-x-i-r-for-n-dimensional-hypersphere-radius

Comment: With Vitali Covering Theorem you should be able to reduce the problem to metric balls, yes?  Since Euclidean balls are hyperbolic ones as sets, it works in either setting.

Comment: @JohnSamples ah ok, I will look into that, this level of real analysis and geometry is not thing but I will see what I can do.

Comment: @JohnSamples I understand the concept of this theorem and yes think this maybe a viable solution, but I can't find any examples application as to how to apply the theorem